# accessing global variables in angular scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_repeat_object

instead of

```
  <div ng-app="" ng-init="names=[
  {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
  {name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
  {name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}]">
```

Is there a syntax to refer to an external variable declared elsewhere in ng-init (and NOT declared in angularjs controller) as this one doesn't work:

```
  <script>
  var myNames = [
  {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
  {name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
  {name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}]
  </script>

  <div ng-app="" ng-init="names=myNames">
```

I know it's bad practice but I use another framework also and don't want to duplicate the content of the variable. And it's just for prototyping not code for real app.

Or else if I use ng-init initial declaration, can I refer it from another script variable ?

Comment: no, there isn't, partially because of the way that angular scopes work, partially because `ng-init` is a directive (so you are passing an expression), and partially because except for extremely simple proof of concept, this isn't something you should use `ng-init` for anyway.

Comment: That demo is a classic display of w3schools promoting bad practices that go against angular docs recommendations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work because of the following reasons

1. Script tag is for to the html document's javascript. It has no relationship with angular's ng-init directive.
2. The [**angular documentation**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) about ngInit directive warns as shown below.

[image: List item]

Best practise is to go with **controllers** when these kind of situations arises.

**Updated as per the discussion in chat**

```
<body>
  <script>
  var myNames = [
  {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
  {name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
  {name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}];

  var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

  app.controller('myController',function($scope){

        $scope.names=window.myNames;

  });
  </script>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
        <p>Looping with objects:</p>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="x in names">{{ x.name + ', ' + x.country }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I know it's bad practice but I use another framework also and don't want to duplicate the content of the variable.

Comment: you can access that variable using **window.myNames**. else where in html document, but you can't use it in the **angular ng-init**.

Comment: not sure to understand:  if I use ng-init initial declaration, can I refer it from another script variable or I can't either ?

Comment: by **another script variable** what you exactly mean about? Another <script> </script> tag in the document? In any ways ngInit does not gets initialised that way.

Comment: do u want the **variable myNames** to be used in the ng-repeat, this can be achieved without ng-init?

Comment: I need to use the content of a variable in 2 different frameworks: one in angular through ng-init for ng-repeat and another which use variable declared in classical script tag.

Comment: @user310291 as shown in question it is a global variable and is therefore accessible anywhere inside your angular app